# String Connection command asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database-connection

I am having difficulties to connect into my databases with the Connection String! It threw my an error every time I try to connect.The error I have is -Index 1 is out of range.
Please any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are there two connection strings defined in your config file? Your code is referencing connection string number two by using [1]. [0] is the first one.

Comment: I used [0], but it gave me this error-The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory. I had this connection installed on my VS2010 but  It did not allow me to connect to databases when I moved my work to VS 2012!?

Comment: I'm guessing the two errors are unrelated. Put a breakpoint after the connection string reference and see if it succeeded. It may be that it does when you use [0], and the other error is a different issue further down the execution path.

Comment: It does not work,it gives me the same exception at the connection string?:(

Comment: Can you post your Web.config file?  X out the username password if you're not using integrated security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
Web.config file

```
   <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=JBC;Integrated Security=True" />
```

.cs file

```
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
```

Define connstr globally (outside of events and methods) and declare con=new SqlConnection(connstr) in page_load event. So you wont be require to declare it again and again and can call con anywhere in page once declared